# Devise игнорирует пользовательские поля

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails

Воозникла проблема с гемом `devise`. В качестве служебной модели я выбрал `Users`:

```
rails g devise User
```

А затем расширил её, добавив в таблицу дополнительные данные:

```
rails g migration AddFieldsToUsers birthday:date nick:string gender:string client:string
```

Дополнил форму регистрации:

```
h2 Sign up

= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f|
  = devise_error_messages!

  div
    = f.label :email
    br
    = f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true

  div
    = f.label :nick
    br
    = f.text_field :nick

  div
    = f.label :password
    br
    = f.password_field :password, :required => true

  div
    = f.label :password_confirmation
    br
    = f.password_field :password_confirmation, :required => true

  div
    = f.label :birthday
    br
    = f.date_field :birthday, :required => true

  div
    = f.label :gender
    br
    = f.select :gender, [[:male, 'male'], [:female, 'female']], :required => true

  div = f.submit "Sign up"

= render "devise/shared/links"
```

Форма отображается нормально, миграция также отработала без ошибок, но все не "родные" поля формы просто не обрабатываются. Кто скажет, в чём проблема и как её обойти?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вероятно, всё дело в Strong Parameters.

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters

  protected

  # added custom fields :birthday, nick, gender, client
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
      u.permit(:name, :birthday, :nick, :gender, :client, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end

  end

end
```

Больше инфы на [старничке гема в гитхабе](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) в разделе Strong Parameters