# Rails не видит введенных в форме данных

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

У меня сразу несколько вопросов:

1. Добавил в Devise атрибуты `name` (`string`) и `phone` (`integer`). При отправке формы выдает ошибки "Name can't be blank" и "Phone can't be blank", хотя поля заполнены.
2. Как заменить лэйблы (например, перевести на русский)? Когда меняю `:name` на `:ФИО` - все нормально, но когда меняю остальные - выдает ошибку.

Сама форма:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, 
                         :url => registration_path(resource_name), 
                         :html => { :role => 'form'}) do |f| %>
    <h3>Регистрация</h3>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :name %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :email %><br />
      <%= f.email_field :email %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :phone %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :phone %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
     <%= f.submit 'Sign up', :class => 'button right' %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Под каждый из вопросов лучше заводить отдельную тему. Так вы сможете точнее назвать вопрос, получить больше качественных ответов и облегчите поиск остальным участникам, кто столкнется с аналогичной проблемой.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Добавил в Devise атрибуты `name` (`string`) и `phone` (`integer`). При отправке формы выдает ошибки "Name can't be blank" и "Phone can't be blank", хотя поля заполнены.

Скорее всего, вы наступили на те же грабли, что и я [когда-то](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/292408/devise-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F), забыв про Strong Parameters.

> Как заменить лэйблы (например перевести на русский)? Когда меняю `:name` на `:ФИО` - все нормально, но когда меняю остальные - выдает ошибку.

Разумеется, выдаёт. Надо `'ФИО'`, а не `:ФИО` и так далее. С двоеточия начинаются ключи, а вам надо задать конкретное строковое значение. Однако, если вы собираетесь именно переводить, то лучше сразу начинать использовать [API интернационализации](http://rusrails.ru/rails-internationalization-i18n-api).